# How to use Comparator?

Tags: java, algorithm, comparator

I'm trying to write some code and I need to use a comparator, but I have no idea what a comparator is. Could you please explain why we use Comparators and what is comparable?

And also am I doing this correctly? I tried to use implements Comparator<> on the top, but it was not working.

Here is my code.

```
 import java.util.Comparator;
 public class MedalCount {
 String name;
 int goldMedals;
 int silverMedals;
 int bronzeMedals;
 int totalMedals;


/** 
 * Creates a new MedalCount instance.
 * @param name is the name of the nation
 * @param nGoldMedals is the number of gold medals
 * @param nSilverMedals is the number of silver medals
 * @param nBronzeMedals is the number of bronze medals
 */
public MedalCount(String name, int nGoldMedals, int nSilverMedals,
                  int nBronzeMedals) {
    this.name = name;
    this.goldMedals = nGoldMedals;
    this.silverMedals = nSilverMedals;
    this.bronzeMedals = nBronzeMedals;
    totalMedals = nGoldMedals + nSilverMedals + nBronzeMedals;
}

/** Return a string describing the medal count information for the country */
public String toString() {
    return name + ":\t" + goldMedals + ",\t" + silverMedals + ",\t" 
        + bronzeMedals + ",\t"+ totalMedals;
}

/** 
 * Compare instance of medal count with another. 
 * Nations compared based on number of total medals (descending order).
 */
// TODO: create comparator
public static final Comparator<MedalCount> COMPARATOR = new Comparator<MedalCount>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MedalCount totalMedals1, MedalCount TotalMedals2) {
        if (totalMedals1.totalMedals >= totalMedals1.totalMedals) {
            return 1;
        } else
            return 0;


    }
}




/** Comparator for sorting by nation name alphabetically */
// TODO: create comparator


/** Comparator for sorting by gold medal count (descending order) */
// TODO: create comparator
```

}

Answer (score 2):

It's used to do equality checking. Let's say you have a list of objects belonging to the same class. The class has 3 properties you can say they are equal if all 3 bits of data are the same. But you could also say second property has higher precedence over 3rd and 1st property comes last. So it's how operators like <, <= = =>, >, <> behave when comparing a list of said objects. So you can then do things like sort a list of objects for that class.

Additional background is available from [the Comparator javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is on this line: `if (totalMedals1.totalMedals >= totalMedals1.totalMedals)`

You need to compare BOTH objects, you have `totalMedals1` twice and never use `totalMedals2`.

Answer (score 1):

> your condition is wrong in compare method both object is same. change totalMedals1 to totalMedals2
>
> when you sort your objects these interface used, like example you want use Collections.sort(ListOfMedal) based on this logic your object will get sorted
>
> Comparable provides single sorting sequence and Comparator provides you multiple sorting sequences, try with below code

```
if (totalMedals1.totalMedals >= totalMedals2.totalMedals) return 1;
if (totalMedals1.totalMedals <= totalMedals2.totalMedals) return -1;
else return 0;
```